# Solve gives an empty output

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following system, but it gives me an empty output:

```
x1 = \[Alpha] Cosh [p a/h] - \[Sigma] Cos [q a/h] + \[Rho] Sin [q a/h]
x2 = \[Sigma] Cos [q (a + d)/h] - \[Rho] Sin [q (a + d)/h] - Exp [-p (a + d)/h]
x3 = p \[Alpha]/h Sinh [p a/h] + q \[Sigma] /h Sin [qa/h] + q \[Rho] /h Cos [qa/h]
x4 = - q \[Sigma]/h Sin [q (a + d)/h] - q \[Rho] /h Cos[q (a + d)/h] + p/h Exp [-p (a + d)/h]

Solve [{x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0, x4 == 0}, {\[Sigma], \[Rho], \[Alpha]}]
```

Comment: An empty output means there is no solution. Was your code copied straight from Mathematica? The Greek letters should be `\[Alpha]` I think. If your original code just had `[Alpha]` Mathematica will not know how to interpret that.

Comment: Solve gives generic solutions, that is solutions that are not only valid for special values of the parameters. If `{}` is returned, it means that no such solution exists. To also get solutions that are only valid for special parameter values you use `Reduce`, however as this is a much harder job, it may take much longer.

Comment: You have 4 equations and just 3 unknowns.  If you drop any one of the equations, then there is a unique solution.

Comment: You have two `qa` that should probably be `q a`